# Any suggestions on how to run a Selenium test so it checks whether a website exists?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2017

I need to run a test that confirms a website can be obtained from the web. This is what I have so far but I am pretty sure it is wrong, any input or tips would be appreciated, thanks!

```
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");

        using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), chromeOptions))
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.azurewebsites.net/");
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(d => d.Title.StartsWith("", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "https://example.azurewebsites.net/");
        }
```

Comment: Use Ping to get response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your purpose is just to check if the site is alive or not, HttpRequest is a better way than Selenium. You can just send a simple GET request to the URL and check the status code.
If the site is alive, you will get 200.
I used this method for checking a router connection status before. 
I sent GET request to 'https://www.google.com/' and checked the status.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Furthermore, Selenium is much slower because it needs to load all the web elements.

Answer (score 0):

**To check a website is up or not, you can use the below code:**

**Java:**

```
public boolean checkWebStatus(String url, int timeout) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
                .openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            return true;
        }
        else
          return false;

}
```

**C#**

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

***Or you can perform an HTTP HEAD request against the URL***

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("your url");
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Method = "HEAD";
try {
    response = request.GetResponse();
    //Check response here
} catch (WebException wexp)
{
    //Catch exception
}
```

**NOTE:** Using **SELENIUM** to just check whether a site is up or not, is not advisable and much slower than the upper implementation.